# CSS overflow scroll auto

Tags: css

Can somebody please tell me what is the difference between `auto` and `scroll` value for the property `overflow`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`overflow: scroll;` makes the scrollbar always visible, whereas `overflow: auto;` will add the scroll bar only if needed.

Comment: Please search for yourself before asking the question next time.